# direct sum of null space and range space

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose A $\in$ L ($\mathcal{R^4}$) such that   A(x) is given by the following vector in $\mathcal{R^4}$ \begin{bmatrix} 
x_2 + x_3 \\
x_3 \\
0\\
0  
\end{bmatrix} 
Can I get $\mathcal{R^4}$ = N$_A$ $\bigoplus$ R$_A$ ? If not, any suggestion for choosing subspaces X and Y of $\mathcal{R^4}$ to satisfy this direct sum formula ?
What I get is:  N$_A$ is the set of vectors such as [x$_1$,0,0,x$_4$] in which x$_1$,x$_4$ $\in$ $\mathcal{R}$; and R$_A$ is the set of vectors such as [x$_2$+x$_3$, x$_3$, 0, 0] in which x$_2$,x$_3$ $\in$ $\mathcal{R}$. But I find it is a bit impossible to write $\mathcal{R^4}$ as a direct sum of null space and range space.

Comment: Check that $(1,0,0,0)^t$ lies in both the null space and the range so you cannot get $\mathbb{R}^4 = \mathbf{N}_A\oplus \mathbf{R}_A$. Asto “choosing subspaces to satisfy the direct sum formula”, there’s lots and lots; in fact, given *any* subspace for $X$ you can find infinitely many choices for $Y$. You presumably, though, want subspaces satisfying *some* conditions.

Comment: That's because $\mathbb R^4$ is _not_ the internal direct sum of those two spaces, because in fact those two spaces have a non-trivial intersection (which is $\operatorname{span}(\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}^T)$. But $\mathbb R^4$ is _isomorphic to_ the (external) direct sum of the two spaces, and this is obvious from their dimensions.

Comment: Other conditions are (i) two subspaces are both invariant subspaces (ii) dimension are both two.

Comment: First, you should put all the information in the question. Were you hoping we would *guess* these conditions? Sorry; the government really doesn’t like it when I read minds without a warrant. Second, “invariant” doesn’t mean anything by itself. It should be invariant relative to **something**... (presumably... the action of $A$?)

Comment: Given A $\in$ L(X),  Y $\subset$ X subspace of X s.t.  A(Y) $\subset$ Y, then we say Y is an invariant subspace of X.

Comment: @Eric - given $A \in L(X)$ and $Y$ a subspace of $X$, if $A(Y) \subset Y$, then we say "$Y$ is an invariant subspace of $X$ *with respect to $A$*".

Comment: @PaulSinclair, yeah, it is correct. thanks,